# How to add longitude / latitude to a world map in MapInfo professional?

Tags: mapinfo, latitude-longitude

I am a novice in MapInfo Professional. I have imported a shapefile of the world map into MapInfo. It's projected as Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection (ETRS89). Is it possible to show the longitude / latitude as well?

After what I have read in the forums, I am guessing I could do something with Grid maker or grid tools?

I can't find any specified steps for this requirement.

Comment: are you after just graticule lines? or needing to re-project the data into WGS84? Which Version of MapInfo do you have?

Answer (score 1):

**Create a dynamic graticule (graticule.mbx)**

*To add a graticule to a map, select "Add Graticule"; to remove a graticule select "Remove Graticule". These commands can be found on the Graticule sub-menu on the Tools menu, or when you right-click on a map window. Note: you can only have 10 windows with graticules at any one time in any one MapInfo session. If this is a problem for you, remove the graticule from one of the windows, or re-compile the programme with a higher limit.
Once you have added a graticule to a window, the graticule will re-draw as you pan and zoom in and out, and as you change projection.
The graticule will usually be in the current coordinate system - e.g. with a New Zealand Map Grid projection you get an NZMG grid. However if the coordinate system is a non-degrees system (like NZMG, which is in metres) and you set map coordinate units to Degrees (in Map Options) you will get degree lines projected into the current system. This will usually give you some sort of interesting curvey lines for your "grid".**

http://mapinfotools.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=9&sobi2Id=398&Itemid=53